# I would like to limit the number of radio buttons being generated by surveyCreator in surveyjs library when I select radiogroup question type

Tags: reactjs, surveyjs

When I select the radio group option type, as in the attached image, the number of options given is six. I need to reduce the number of options to be 2,that is, item 1 and item 2 only and have one plus icon. [RadioGroup option type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd61t.png).

I have tried using this code:

```
 creator.toolbox
    .getItemByName("radiogroup")
    .json
    .choices = [
      { text: "Option 1", value: 1 },
      { text: "Option 2", value: 2 },
    ];
```

as suggested from the documentation but still it doesn't work.
Also, I tried this code:

```
PropertyGridEditorCollection.register({
    
    fit: function (prop) {
      return prop.type === "radiogroup";
    },
   
    getJSON: function (obj, prop, options) {
      console.log("obj", obj);
      return { type: "radiogroup", choices: ["Option 1"] };
    }
  });
```

But again it didn't work. Any help or suggestions on this will really go a long way.